# SQL query returns row via phpMyAdmin but not on web site

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have encountered a weird problem, where my query does not return anything when I run it on my web site, but when I run it in phpMyAdmin it returns 1 row.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT post_date, post_id, ref_user_id FROM forum_posts WHERE post_id = (SELECT MAX(post_id) FROM forum_posts WHERE ref_post_id = $row->ref_post_id AND NOT deleted = 1 LIMIT 1) LIMIT 1");

echo $this->db->last_query().'<br>';
echo $query->num_rows();
```

num_rows() gives me 0. I copy the line of code that last_query() gives me and paste it into phpMyAdmin where it returns 1 row.

Any ideas why I does not work on my web site?

Thanks!

Comment: You should check your database connection settings. May be that you are connected to the wrong database.

Comment: @stigok Nope, other queries executed earlier works just fine.

Comment: Are you sure the variables in your SQL string are evaluating to what you thenk they are try `print_r("SELECT post_date, post_id, ref_user_id FROM forum_posts WHERE post_id = (SELECT MAX(post_id) FROM forum_posts WHERE ref_post_id = $row->ref_post_id AND NOT deleted = 1 LIMIT 1) LIMIT 1")` and see what comes out...

Comment: @prodigitalson Get the same thing as last_query()

Comment: have to ask, in case of 2+ environments, are they both looking at the same database with proper permissions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the string in your query to reference PHP variables:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT post_date, post_id, ref_user_id FROM forum_posts 
         WHERE post_id = (SELECT MAX(post_id) 
                         FROM forum_posts WHERE ref_post_id = " . $row->ref_post_id . " AND NOT deleted = 1 LIMIT 1) LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: not entirely true. What most likely is needed here is braces around the call. `{$row->ref_post_id}`

Comment: That could work too. One of the two needs to happen since he just has his variable directly in the query.